# Errors in Eclipse.... Can not find the tag library descripto

Tags: eclipse, spring, tomcat, maven, spring-mvc

Below is my code

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

In Eclipse I get the following error but if I run the code in tomcat it works. why am I getting this eclipse in eclipse

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" enrollment1.jsp /Enroll/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/flows/start line 3  JSP Problem
```

Comment: Is the JSTL library on the project's Java Build Path?

Comment: yes. I see jstl-jstl-1.2/jar

Comment: And you're sure that's the right URI?  What does content assist at the start of the URI value offer?

Comment: huh? I know know what you mean

Comment: Where is the .jar located?  If you've just added it to the Tomcat lib folder, Eclipse wouldn't necessarily know it's been added.

Comment: Do you also have the library `taglibs:standard:1.1.2` in your build path?